# What are the implications of inheriting ChainlinkClient in a UUPS upgradeable smart contract?

Tags: chainlink

Chainlink doesn't *currently* provide an upgradeable version of its contracts, such as [Openzeppelin upgradeable contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable).

For example, in order to inherit the ChainlinkClient in a UUPS upgradeable smart contract, we need to create and update our own instance and remove the initialization of `s_requestCount` variable, since all the storage assignments must be done within the `initialize()` method, as also pointed [here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/4976#issuecomment-1373875614).

Once this update is made, the ChainlinkClient contract appears to be upgrade safe.

However, I'm wondering if there are any other considerations or consequences involved when employing this approach behind the scenes?